# `.show()` inconsistent behaviour (bug?)

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden element `$myHiddenElement`. Now if I do

`$myHiddenElement.show();`

all is OK. However, if I do

`$myHiddenElement.show(300);`

then `$myHiddenElement` gets the attribute `display: block;` which damages my layout.

Comment: yes, but without code we can't do anything

Comment: What kind of element is your hidden element? A block element?

Comment: @All: I'm trying to reproduce the thing on jsfiddle. I'll be back when I succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a jQuery-bug (in older versions) that could be causing this.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ux8xL/1/ working with 1.6.2 whereas when you go back to 1.2.6 ( http://jsfiddle.net/Ux8xL/2/)  it's not taking into account the inline-display rule from the CSS.

EDIT: I am assuming your hidden element is a block element that is set to inline-behavior. In case not: ?

Answer (score 1):

It uses display:block; to create the animation, thats why it only comes when you put a timer on it.

Basicly you should just be able to float:left and display:block on the element - which would produce the same as display:inline-block or whatever you are using now.